# Getting Odd or Even ID in Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, lumen

I have a task that needs to be displayed every type of holiday where id is odd number.And when I tried to do it in Eloquent it always gives me an error.

Query

```
Select holiday_type.id, holiday_type.name
From holiday_type
Where (holiday_type.id % 2) = 0;
```

Laravel PHP

```
return DB::table('holiday_type')
       ->select('holiday_type.id','holiday_type.name as text')
    // ->where(('id%2'), '=', 0)) ** I also tried different format but still nothing 
       ->get();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `DB::raw()` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: ->where('id', '<>', 1)
->where('id', '<>', 3) ->where('id', '<>', 5)
        ->where('id', '<>', 7)

Comment: this what i did but is there any easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [raw expression](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

```
DB::table('holiday_type')
    ->select(DB::raw('holiday_type.id, holiday_type.name as text'))
    ->whereRaw('MOD(id, 2) = 0')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hi @Alfa thanks for your response. I tried your but its Null.

Comment: Hi @AlyssaAndrea, I've updated my answer. Please check out.

Comment: Hi @Alfa now its working. thanks for your help. Have a nice day :))))))